# Probability of getting two pairs from a standard deck of cards.

Tags: probability, card-games

A random 5 card poker hand is picked from a standard deck of cards. Find the probability of getting two different pairs(e.g., two 3’s, two 7’s, and an Ace).

The answer I found online:
$$\frac{{\binom{13}{2}.\binom{4}{2}}^2.44}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

But, I think it should be:
$$\frac{{\binom{13}{2}.\binom{3}{1}}^2.44}{\binom{52}{5}},$$ where $$\binom{13}{2}\text{ is the number of ways of selecting any 2 cards from a suit, i.e., 13 cards, and}$$
$$\binom{3}{1}\text{ is the number of ways of selecting 1 card out of remaining 3 same card to form a pair}$$
$$\binom{3}{1}^2\text{denotes ways of selecting both pairs, and}$$
$$\text{44 - total number of ways of selecting 5th card which doesn't belong to any pair, and}$$
$$\binom{52}{2}\text{ is the number of ways of selecting 5 cards out of total 52 cards}$$

Can someone please help me figuring out the correct one? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event is to obtain *two from thirteen* **kinds** *each* of *two from four* **suits**$^\star$, and *one from eleven* kind of *one from fourty-four* **cards** not of those kinds; when selecting *five from all fifty-two* cards.$$\dfrac{\dbinom{13}2\dbinom 42^2~\dbinom {11}1\dbinom41}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$

---

$\star$ You must obtain the two of each kind and *both* suits for each of them.

Comment: Yup..you are absolutely right. Thanks +25 :)